# Installed more ram /boot/efi not found... How to fix?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, ram

So, I just installed more RAM. Now I can't boot (properly) into xubuntu.

When booting I'm greeted with something along the lines of "Failed to load /boot/efi, press S to continue or press M to manually recover".

If I press S it loads, but everything's wonky - my wireless mouse doesn't work, my extra monitor isn't automatically added, and my background reverts to the default xubuntu one (after briefly showing my actual background!)

The drive is partitioned, I have xubuntu, windows 8.1 (properly set up, as far as I know..) and a partition for shared files between the two. In `/etc/fstab` it lists `/boot/efi` as the mountpoint for `/dev/sda2`. GRUB also lists `/dev/sda2` as the windows bootloader point.

Any help is appreciated, I'll post whatever logs I can get from the recovery console at request.

EDIT: It seems that the RAM is fine, as far as I can tell. The BIOS is recognizing it fine, and windows is running well (that's what I'm typing from now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, unbeknownst to me, was that I ran apt-get upgrade and forgot that I did. It had a kernel fix, and this version was unable to find /boot/efi, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Despite what you say in your edit, I have to suspect you have bad RAM. Sometimes bad RAM creates more problems in one OS than in another, just because of the way each OS uses RAM. I therefore recommend that you run a memory-test program. On an EFI-based computer, the commercial (but free) [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) can do the job; there's a version that will run in the EFI, before any OS has loaded.

You could also try pulling the RAM and re-inserting it. Sometimes RAM is OK but will be flaky because it wasn't properly seated.

Comment: So! I pulled the RAM, re-inserted it. Still getting the issue, but only in Ubuntu. Something I didn't try before, was the 'advanced options for ubuntu' in GRUB. Turns out, it's a kernel issue - the newest kernel causes the issue, but older versions don't.